# NSRegularExpression matching one or more alphanumeric

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsregularexpression

I have the following URL:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/picoftheday/media/recent?access_token=29088696%2Efd3325f%2E7e277194e17340788abc72583dfd48b3

and the following regular expression:

```
 NSRegularExpression * regexTags = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"tags/\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+/media/recent" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
   NSArray* tagMatch = [regexTags matchesInString:self.currentRequestURL_
                                                 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.currentRequestURL_ length])];
```

Why doesn't this match with the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the REGEX itself

The regex 
`@"tags/\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+/media/recent"` matches  **tags/\picoftheday/media/recent**

but you need **`tags/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/media/recent`** to match **tags/picoftheday/media/recent**

there is helpful online tester to test your regex if it matches the string or not http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Oh sorry i will change it, it should formatted as code to render the second back slash :)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the double backslash from the expression. You have:

```
@"tags/\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+/media/recent"
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
@"tags/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/media/recent"
```

The double backslash is converted to a single backslash which means it escapes the opening square bracket. This means the expression is looking for an actual open square bracket in the string instead of opening the character group.

Comment: I saw that. Yours actually had a better explanation. I'll update mine to include that info.